# MS Access: Allow user to update data from form, but not from table

Tags: ms-access

I want to allow user to update data from form, but not from direct table. I added Before Change event on table, and raising error if the user group is 'basic'. This is working as expected if I enter data in table. But, it is also raising error even if saving data from form. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The normal route is to distribute you application as an accde which is compiled and the objects can't be directly "got at" if you design it correctly.

Comment: you can put user entered data into datatable and make your changes or validation etc which are requried, after that update that data on sql table as you requried.

Comment: If you use the before_change event to audit the record properly, then it wouldn't matter whether the change happened from the table interface or the form interface. If you are just being bullheaded about making the user enter data only from your form, then use code in the before_update event handler that recognizes the form is being used

Comment: Please revise your question to show the code in your Before Change event

Answer (score 1):

In general the way to deal with permissions in Access is to only ever show your users the forms; they should never directly interact with a table or query.  So instead of adding Before Change code to your table, you instead want to hide the table.

The things you need are in the Current Database section of the Access options.  For this example I'll assume you just have the one form, but the same applies if you have many forms and a "Home" form.

1. Use the "Display Form" dropdown to select the form you want the user to see when they open the application.
2. Un-check "Use Access Special Keys" to prevent keyboard shortcuts showing objects you don't want shown.
3. Un-check "Display Navigation Pane" to hide the object list.
4. Un-check "Allow Full Menus" to prevent users from creating new objects (or use other database development functions)

With this done, the user will see only the form interface you selected and the basic data entry toolbar.

Note that when you want to make changes to the file as a developer you must hold down `Shift` when opening the application, which will display the navigation pane etc.  Of course, any user who knows about the `Shift` override could do the same.  Which is why distributing in a compiled `accde`, which cannot be unlocked, is a good idea.  But you need to set up the application using the above options before that matters.